# pyodbc query returns multiple backslashes

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am trying to execute a simple query, which I will, later on, write into a docx.
The query looks something like this:

```
db_con = DB_CONNECTION()
with db_con.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("Select " + column + " \
                    FROM table.example \
                    WHERE code = '" + requirement +"' AND " + column + " != '';")

    rows = []
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
         rows.append(str(row)[2:-4])
return rows
```

All rows returned, in this case, are comments, that have been collected. Some of which contain newlines.
In the database the newlines are saved as `"\n"`. fetching them with pyodbc causes them to be returned as `"\\n"` and in some cases `"\\\\n"`. (changing between those two alternatives even for the same row)

**Does anyone know why pyodbc does this? Or how I can avoid this?**

My ugly solution would be to write a function, which searches for `"\\"` and if found -> searches for further adjacent backslashes and replace them all with a single one.

Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confused by Python's *representation* of a string that contains backslashes.

```
>>> backsl = chr(0x5c)  # string containing a single backslash
>>> hello = "Hello" + backsl + "n" + "world!"

>>> # printing the string looks normal
>>> print(hello)
Hello\nworld!

>>> the default string *representation* doubles up the backslash
>>> hello
'Hello\\nworld!'
>>> str(hello)
'Hello\\nworld!'

# if you call `repr()` and then print() or str() that then the backslashes get doubled again
>>> rep = repr(hello)
>>> print(rep)
'Hello\\nworld!'
>>> rep
"'Hello\\\\nworld!'"
>>> str(rep)
"'Hello\\\\nworld!'"
```

Note that just dumping a value to the console — e.g., `>>> hello` — does an implicit `str()` on it.